# SQL Query optimization for Join containing the DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB with two tables:

1. Employee:

```
EmpID(int, PK, AI, NOT NULL),
Name(varchar(256), NOT NULL),
ContractExpire(datetime, NOT NULL)
```

2. Transaction:

```
ID(int, PK, AI, NOT NULL),
EmpID(int, NOT NULL),
Action(int, NOT NULL),
Status(int, NOT NULL)
```

[image: DB Table Overview]

Each employee can have multiple transactions like `Joined`, `Exited`, `Went on a long holiday` of type int (enum). The `Employee` table consists around 1,00,00,000 entries and each employee will have 2-3 entries in the `Transaction` table. I have the below SQL query and it is costing a huge execution time.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(emps.EmpID) 
FROM Employee emps 
INNER JOIN Transactions Trxs ON emps.EmpID = Trxs.EmpID 
WHERE Trxs.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) from Transactions WHERE EmpID = emps.EmpID) 
    AND Trxs.Status = 20 
    AND emps.ContactExpire > '2024-04-10'
```

A user can have different status codes and **20** means active (it is not ordered and cannot be ordered). The expected outcome is to get a count of all the active employees whose latest status is 20 and contract is expiring after 10.Apr.2024.

Could there be a more optimal way to optimize query?

Note/limitations:

1. Connection is initiated via ODBC
2. Raw SQL queries must be used. ORMs (like EF) are not allowed
3. Stored procedures are not allowed
4. Primarily MS SQL Server but can also be MySQL or SQLite

Already attempted:

1. DATEDIFF
2. DATEADD
3. DateTime ('2024-04-10 15:16:19.000')
4. Indexing EmpID in Transaction table
5. Indexing ContractExpire in Employee table
6. ExecutionPlan

Comment: Don't post images of schema, code, sample data, or results. The markdown format allows formatting tabular data, and you should do that instead.

Comment: What's the definition of the transaction table? And what does the query plan looks like. 1 M rows shouldn't take more than a 10 of secs with proper indexes and hardware

Comment: Also, what is `lcs`?

Comment: you can use `select * from emp cross apply (select top 1 * from transactions t where t.EmpID = emp.EmpID ORDER BY ID DESC) tr where ... ` to avoid the ugly sub-query

Comment: Can I buy shares in this company that has 1,00,00,000 Employees?

Comment: @codeulike would you wanna buy a share in a company who scrimps on decent hardware to run the above query in microseconds?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: _lcs_ was a typo, I corrected it. I will post with markdown next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The expected outcome is to get a count of all the active employees whose latest status is 20 and contact[sic] is expiring after 10.Apr.2024.

Try this:

```
WITH NumberedTx AS (
    SELECT e.EmpID, t.Status
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmpID ORDER BY t.ID DESC) rn
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN Transactions t ON e.EmpID = t.EmpID 
    WHERE e.ContractExpire > '20240410'
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID)
FROM NumberedTx 
WHERE rn = 1 AND Status = 20
```

Though I'd feel a little better if the `Transactions` table had a datetime column, in the case of someone needing to backdate entries (such as entering a vacation after the fact), where the latest ID might no longer be the latest record.

---

Here's another option that occurred to me later. It simplifies the `WHERE` clause a bit:

```
WITH EmpLastStatus AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT e.EmpID
        , first_value(t.Status) OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmpID ORDER BY t.ID DESC) [Status]
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN Transactions t ON e.EmpID = t.EmpID 
    WHERE e.ContractExpire > '20240410'
)
SELECT COUNT(EmpID)
FROM EmpLastStatus 
WHERE Status = 20
```

A future version of SQL Server (or current version of Azure SQL) will let you simplify this further with the `QUALIFY` keyword, so no nesting, subquery, or CTE is needed at all:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.EmpID)
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Transactions t ON e.EmpID = t.EmpID 
WHERE e.ContractExpire > '20240410'
QUALIFY 20 = first_value(t.Status) OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmpID ORDER BY t.ID DESC)
```

But again: the above does not (yet) work with on-premise SQL Server.

Comment: A `Datetime` column makes much easier but one of the limitation is not to change the schema.
Will this query provide the result with **latest** status to be **20**?

Comment: @mDev Inasmuch as you can define "latest" by transaction ID, then yes it will. But if people can backdate entries, this information is currently LOST, and not actually preserved in the data based on the schema shown.

Comment: I used my query and yours in a batch with _Estimated Execution Plan_ and your query takes **57%**. I have not done actual execution yet but I want to educate myself and understand. A short info would be really a great help.

Comment: @mDev Generally, filtering on a windowing function result is faster than an additional correlated subquery (or lateral join/apply). But there are times the query engine can surprise us. Either way, you may want to test actual execution times.

Comment: @mDev and I just though of an even better way to do this using first_value() instead. This is now part of the answer.

Comment: @jcoehoorn On the practical side, the first and second queries were fast compared to mine. I had to analyse and add the index with the help of _Estimated Execution Plan_ then it went fast. My query used to take 20 seconds when DB server was idle and yours took 3 seconds. So your query yielded 7 times faster result.
Thanks to you.


I would like to mark it as resolved, but could you please explain what is happening in one of the 2 queries, so that it can be helpful for other developers?

Comment: @jcoehoorn: Also, is it DB provider independent? Will it work with MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: The short version is these work by looking at window function partitions. SQLite does support window functions, but the exact syntax may be slightly different, as different SQL dialects sometimes have variances in how a feature is implemented. For example, 3 of the 4 current answers here used `20240410` instead of `2024-04-10` for the date literal, because `yyyyMMdd` (no separators!) is the **correct date literal format** for SQL Server and the `yyyy-MM-dd` format is actually **wrong** for SQL Server, even if it seems to work most of the time... but it's **correct** for Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(emps.EmpID) 
FROM Employee emps 
INNER JOIN (SELECT empId, MAX(ID) as lastId 
  from Transactions 
  group by empId) trxs ON emps.EmpID = Trxs.EmpID 
inner join Transactions tr on tr.Id = trxs.LastId
WHERE tr.Status = 20 AND emps.ContactExpire > '20240410';
```

This should be a little better.

Comment: I also used my query and yours in a batch with _Estimated Execution Plan_ and your query takes **55%**.

Answer (score 0):

This index should be all you need, your original query is fine:

```
create index ix_emp on Transactions (EmpId, Id desc) include (Status)
```

It could be written more clearly with cross apply, but that's a matter of taste:

```
select count(*) from Employee e
cross apply (
    select top 1 * from Transactions
    where EmpId = e.EmpId
    order by Id desc) last_tx
where last_tx.Status = 20
    and e.ContactExpire > '2024-04-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me old school but sometimes a temp table is worth trying, especially if the proportion of employees with `ContractExpire > '20240410'` is only a fraction of the total. The idea is that this forces the optimiser to only spend time looking at the subset that you're interested in.

```
SELECT e.EmpID, t.Status, t.Id
INTO #temptransactions
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Transactions t ON e.EmpID = t.EmpID 
WHERE e.ContractExpire > '20240410'

-- creating index is optional but will probably help
CREATE INDEX idx_temptransactions on #temptransactions(EmpId, Id)


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.EmpID) 
FROM #temptransactions t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT EmpId,MAX(Id) as maxId 
          FROM #temptransactions t2
          GROUP BY EmpId) newest
    ON newest.EmpId = t1.EmpId
    AND newest.maxId = t1.Id
WHERE t1.Status = 20
```